# How to update my Dockerfile to package the app inside the container using gcloud registry?

Tags: docker, google-cloud-platform

I am trying to get my application to build using gcloud's:

1. source register
2. container registry
3. compute engine

So my current Dockerfile looks like this:

```
FROM ruby:2.5-alpine

RUN apk update && apk --update add \
 build-base \
 nodejs \
 postgresql-dev \
 tzdata \
 imagemagick

# yarn
ENV PATH=/root/.yarn/bin:$PATH
RUN apk add --virtual build-yarn curl && \
    touch ~/.bashrc && \
    curl -o- -L https://yarnpkg.com/install.sh | sh && \
    apk del build-yarn


RUN mkdir /app
COPY . /app
WORKDIR /app

RUN bundle install --binstubs
CMD puma -C config/puma.rb
```

My current workflow is to push my code to a server, and then I build the image and then use docker-compose to start the project.

I am trying to get this to work using google cloud platform.

I am using their source repositiry (git) service, and also container registry.

How should I update my Dockerfile to grab the source code from source registry?

I then have push this to the container registry to build the image.

Answer (score 0):

According to your description, I think you need a CI/CD server (such as jenkins).

1. [Code] Update your code and push to git
2. [Build] Jenkins triger by git push event.
3. [Build] Use Jenkins to pull your code and build new docker image
4. [Artifact managemnt] Jenkins push new docker image to container registry
5. [Deploy] Use Jekins to trigger server pull new image and run it.

If you don't have jenkins, you may try pure cloud solution provide by GCP [cloud-build](https://cloud.google.com/cloud-build/docs/overview)

[image: CI/CD]